# How to make dynamic table in jade

Tags: html, pug

I have just started working in jade and unable to find out the mistake. I know it will be very basic but the spaces are so irritating.Can anyone help me ?
Also i want to ask is there any method to make similar dynamic table in html without using any template engine?

```
  html
  head
    title= title
  body
  div(class="container")
   table(class='table table-striped')
     thead
      tr
       th Description
       th Category
       th Budget
       th City
      each item in items
      tr
       td=item.desc
       td=item.category
       td=item.email
       td=item.mobile
```

The error here is i think due to spaces that why in browser only these codes are showind despite of tables. I will appreciate any type of help :)

Comment: What do you see in the browser? Are you getting any errors when compiling? What is the compiled HTML? Does the indentation in the Pug code in the question match the indentation you're using extactly?

Comment: @sean i am seeing the above code wrritten in browser only not the table

Comment: You're seeing the Pug code in the browser? Are you compiling it or just loading Pug in the browser?

Comment: @Sean i didn't know that i have to compile it in such way. As i mentioned i am totally a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug is a templating language that can be compiled into HTML. Web browsers can't interpret Pug by itself—it has to be compiled before being loaded by a browser. There are a few different build tools that can be used to compile Pug, including [Express](https://expressjs.com/) and [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). For beginners unfamiliar with build tool, I would recommend using [Codepen](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/using-html-preprocessors/) or a GUI app like [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) to get started with compiling.

Once you're up and running, and assuming your `items` array is properly formatted, your Pug code should look something like this:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    div.container
      table.table.table-striped
        thead
          tr
            th Description
            th Category
            th Budget
            th City
        each item in items
          tr
            td=item.desc
            td=item.category
            td=item.email
            td=item.mobile
```